# Extend std::list to cylic list

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I want to implement a cyclic list based on std::list. I want to profit from the benfits of the list but add one specific feature: its iterator operators ++ and -- should hop over the edges and operations (insert/erase) must not invalidate existing iterators. My skills in handling templates are weak and to understand the std containers is an impossible act for me. Hence i need your help. By now im not that far :D. Sorry but even the numerous posts dont help me any further.

EDIT:
Well after a lot of work, a steeeep learnig curve, the failed approach to inherit from std::list::iterator, a short-term depression and a abasing return to your approaches (yes, you all were right) I finally made it.  Inspired by all your contibutions, I can now post what I did the last ... about 12 hours :D Basicly what you suggested, but with nice little operators.

```
#pragma once
#include <list>
using std::list;

template<class T>
class cyclic_iterator;


template<class T>
class cyclicList : public list<T>
{
public:
  typedef cyclic_iterator<T> cyclic_iterator;

  cyclic_iterator cycbegin()
  {// not the purpose, but needed for instanziation
    return cyclic_iterator( *this, this->begin());
  }

  cyclic_iterator cycend()
  {// not the purpose, but needed for instanziation
    return cyclic_iterator( *this, this->end());
  }
};




template<class T>
class cyclic_iterator
{
  public:
  // To hop over edges need to know the container
  cyclic_iterator(){}
  cyclic_iterator(typename list<T>::iterator i)
    : mIter(i){}
  cyclic_iterator(list<T> &c)
    : mContainer(&c){}
  cyclic_iterator(list<T> &c, typename list<T>::iterator i)
    : mContainer(&c), mIter(i){}

  cyclic_iterator<T>& operator=(typename list<T>::iterator i)
  {// assign an interator
    mIter = i;
    return *this;
  }

  cyclic_iterator<T>& operator=(list<T> &c)
  {// assign a container
    mContainer = &c;
    return *this;
  } 

  bool operator==(const cyclic_iterator<T>& rVal) const
  {// check for equality
    return (this->mIter == rVal.mIter && this->mContainer == rVal.mContainer) ? true : false;
  } 

  bool operator!=(const cyclic_iterator<T>& rVal) const
  {//  check for inequality
    return !(this->operator==(rVal));
  } 

  cyclic_iterator<T>& operator++()
  {// preincrement
    ++mIter;
    if (mIter == mContainer->end())
      { mIter = mContainer->begin(); }
    return *this;
  }

  cyclic_iterator<T> operator++(int)
  { // postincrement
    cyclic_iterator<T> tmp = *this;
    ++*this;
    return tmp;
  }

  cyclic_iterator<T>& operator--()
  {// predecrement
    if (mIter == mContainer->begin())
      mIter = --mContainer->end();
    else --mIter;
    return *this;
  }

  cyclic_iterator<T> operator--(int)
  {// postdecrement
    cyclic_iterator<T> tmp = *this;
    --*this;
    return tmp;
  }

  cyclic_iterator<T>& operator+=(int j)
  {// hop j nodes forward
    for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
      ++(*this);
    return *this;
  }

  cyclic_iterator<T>& operator-=(int j)
  {// hop j nodes backwards
    for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
      --(*this);
    return *this;
  }

  T& operator*()
  {
    return *mIter;
  }

  typename list<T>::iterator & getStdIterator()
  {
    return mIter;
  }

private:  
  list<T>*          mContainer;
  typename list<T>::iterator mIter;

};
```

Comment: Standard containers aren't designed to be inherited from. You'd better think about a design with encapsulation instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just make a different iterator type?

```
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

template <typename T, typename Alloc>
struct cyclic_iterator
: std::iterator<typename std::list<T, Alloc>::iterator::iterator_category, T>
{
    typedef std::list<T, Alloc> list_type;

    cyclic_iterator & operator++()
    {
        ++iter;
        if (iter == container.end()) { iter = container.begin(); }
        return *this;
    }

    T & operator*() { return *iter; }

    cyclic_iterator(typename list_type::iterator it, list_type & l)
    : iter(it)
    , container(l)
    {
        if (it == container.end()) { it = container.begin(); }
    }

    // everything else

private:
    typename list_type::iterator iter;
    list_type & container;
};
```

With a helper:

```
template <typename List>
cyclic_iterator<typename List::value_type, typename List::allocator_type>
make_cyclic_iterator(typename List::iterator it, List & l)
{
    return cyclic_iterator<typename List::value_type, typename List::allocator_type>(it, l);
}
```

Usage:

```
// goes round and round forever

for (auto ci = make_cyclic_iterator(mylist.begin(), mylist); ; ++ci)
{
    std::cout << *ci << std::endl;
}
```

(With a few modifications, this code could be made to work on *any* container that exposes `begin`/`end` iterators.)

Comment: I tried implementations like this before but they just turn out well in scenarios where you have to heavily pass iterators around by value. If you don't care for performance, this is probably the way to do it.

Comment: This reminds me of `std::priority_queue`, which lives on top of an existing selectable container like `std::vector`, but provides a different iterator and a different interface.

Comment: I like this approach but " cyclic_iterator<typename list_type::iterator, list_type & l)" causes a lot of errors.

Comment: @DevNoob: Oh, sorry, had a few typos. Don't forget to `#include <iterator>` etc.

Comment: @pmr: I don't follow - the implementation turns out well, so what's the problem?

Comment: @JohanLundberg: container adaptors like the priority queue are complete container classes that are implemented by wrapping a "real" container. That's a somewhat different approach to mine, which is more of an "iterator adaptor". The container adaptors don't usually expose iterators, so the idea is somewhat orthogonal to the present one.

Comment: @KerrekSB In my experience it turned out not to be feasible to have an iterator that is more heavy than a single reference/pointer. But that has also a lot to do with my usage-scenario, where they were heavily passed around as handles. It at least had a large enough performance impact for me to forgo it.

Comment: @pmr: Wait, I thought you claimed that it *did* turn out well? Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. But if one iterator and one reference is too much, then you may indeed need something more low-level that extracts the "end" information directly from the data structure.

Comment: @KerrekSB I meant "didn't turn out well". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. The iterators and the implementation of the end element is implementation specific and not customizable. Containers were not designed for that kind of thing and it would make them really hard. You will have to go through the pain of implementing this yourself. Keep in mind that this gets very tricky because a cyclic list doesn't have a real past-the-end iterator and iterators aren't really able to handle that kind of situation. Some libraries have a Circulator concept to deal with circular structures.

NB: Inheriting from a standard container is a bad idea.

Comment: Okay. As I think of it I think it should be sufficient to add  .prec()/.succ() funktions to the iterator, completely indepentend from the std implementation. This should be possible, isn't it?

Comment: @DevNoob No, I guess you want to add those functions through inheritance, but that will not be possible, because you still wont have access to the iterator internals, which you will need. Besides there is no way you can get from an end-iterator to the begin iterator unless you store a reference to the container. Just implement the thing yourself and don't try to reuse `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can implement it using `std::list`, but first you should encapsulate list in your class and do not derive from it second you must implement your own iterator to accomplish this, but since circular lists are fixed in size I prefer a container with a fixed size and linear memory like `std::array` or `std::vector`.

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>
>
class circular_list {
public:
    // Following typedef are required to make your class a container
    typedef typename Container::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename Container::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename Container::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename Container::const_pointer const_pointer;
    typedef typename Container::reference reference;
    typedef typename Container::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;
public:
    class iterator : std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, value_type> {
    public:
        iterator() : c_(nullptr) {}
        iterator(circular_buffer& c, size_type index)
            : c_( &c.c_ ), index_( index ) {}

        reference operator* () const {
            return (*c_)[index_];
        }
        iterator& operator++ () {
            if( ++index_ >= c_->size() ) index_ = 0;
            return *this;
        }
        iterator& operator-- () {
            if( index_ == 0 ) index_ = c_->size() - 1; else --index_;
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        size_type index_;
        Container* c_;
    };

public:
    void push( const_reference val ) {add item to the container}
    reference current() {return current item from the container}
    void pop() {remove item from the container}

    size_type size() const {return c_.size();}
    iterator begin() {return iterator( *this, 0 );}
    iterator end() {return iterator( *this, size() );}

private:
    friend iterator;
    Container c_;
}
```

Comment: Sorry a neccessary information I omitted: Operations (insert/erase) must not invalidate existing iterators. So std::list is the container of choice. But thanks anyway for your efforts.

Comment: In my version of the code you can simply change the container, in my current implementation you need a container that support random access iterator but I'm pretty sure that you can change the code and handle that part completely!